# Does ADLS support symbolic or alias?

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

Does Azure blob storage support alias for referring to a location or a file?

I am having an Azure subscription and would like to know if ADLS supports alias while referring to a location or a file

If file is available like this - /storage/container/folderA/fileA

I want to do something like this -/foo/pointertofileA

which will still allow me to retrieve the file if I access the above object.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mount the ADLS on your machine. Then you can create a link for the orignal file with an alias in different path like people generally do. For example:

```
ln -s /storage/container/folderA/fileA /foo/pointertofileA
```

You can take a look at the command [`ln`](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uln.htm).